# Run my task before a plugin's task?

Tags: gradle

We're using a gradle file to build a Java WAR file. I know very little about gradle. At the top of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'war'
```

We run the gradle with `gradle clean install`. I'm not sure where these tasks are defined but I assume they're in one of the plugins (I'd guess `war`).

When I run `gradle clean install` it seems to print the tasks that it are run:

```
:clean
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:war
:install
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that the task `install` dependsOn `compileJava`, `processResources`, `classes`, and `war`.

I need a task I've written to run sometime after `clean` but sometime before `war`. Preferably without modifying the plugin.

I've tried indicating that my task `mustRunAfter processResources` but it doesn't work that way.

How can I inject my task as a dependency on `install` before the dependency `war`?

Answer (score 12):

You can declare task dependencies explicitly.

Add following code to your `build.gradle` file

```
tasks.war.dependsOn("yourTaskNameHere")
tasks["yourTaskNameHere"].dependsOn("clean")
```

Comment: This works great but I do have to question... if `install` is dependent on `war` and your first line makes `war` dependent on my task, wouldn't making my task dependent on `install` make it a circular reference?

Comment: Well, it should. My bad, I did not check "install" task's dependencies.
If `clean` is everything you need for your task, just depend on it (I will update the answer)